# Angular Unit Test - Click in directive not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

**Problem**

I'm trying to click on a `radio` input with `value="agency"` from a directive template with the ultimate goal of changing the scope variable `newDatasourceType`.

**Relevant Source**

*Directive template*

```
  <div ng-if="!datasources" class="new-datasource">
        <input name="agencyOrWidget" type="radio" ng-model="newDatasourceType" value="agency" />
        <label>Agency</label>
        <input name="agencyOrWidget" type="radio" ng-model="newDatasourceType" value="widget" />
        <label>Widget</label>
        <select ng-if="newDatasourceType=='widget'" name="{{inputPrefix}}[0][widget_id]">
              <option>Choose a widget...</option>
              <option ng-repeat="(id, options) in widgetList" value="{{id}}">{{id}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-if="newDatasourceType=='agency'" name="{{inputPrefix}}[0][agency_id]">
              <option>Choose an agency...</option>            
              <option ng-repeat="(id, name) in agenciesList" value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

*Relevant Unit Test*

Parts that attempted and notes are in the comments.

```
it('Select Agencies', function() {
    // Running this to see if it does anything
    scope.newDatasourceType = 'agency';

    //create the element with the directive template
    elem = $compile(directive)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    // Returns `1`
    console.log(elem.find('input[value="agency"]').length);

    // elem.find('input[value="agency"]').triggerHandler('click');
    elem.find('input[value="agency"]').click(function() {
        // Doesn't get triggered
        console.log('click');
    });

    // Didn't do anything...
    // scope.$digest();
    // scope.$apply();


    // console.log(elem.html());

    // Test items
    expect(elem.find('select option:nth-child(2)').val()).toBe(Object.keys(scope.agenciesJson)[0]);
});
```

**What I'm Seeing**

Regardless if I manually set `newDatasourceType` or try clicking on it, only the select block with `Choose a widget...` is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `checked` attribute on radiobutton in addition to triggering `click` event. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/k1axxs21/1/

Comment: That worked perfect. I wish I understood why `trigger('click')` worked, but neither `triggerHandler('click')` nor `click()` didn't work.

Comment: All methods: `trigger('click')`, `triggerHandler('click')`, `click()` should work, expect `click(function(){...})` since here you're adding a new handler instead of firing an event. The main idea here is to change `checked` propetry too since angular checks it on each click event at radiobutton and changes model state https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1431